# How to have a PyQT program keep refreshing one widget, always providing an up-to-date value?

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm learning to program with PyQT4 and Python. I'm trying to code a simple app that will display the current CPU usage in a QLCD widget. For CPU usage I'm using psutils module.

The problem is that the CPU usage is not updated all the time - it only records the CPU usage at the moment the app has been launched (I'm guessing), and then it just stops. So, I'm looking for some sort of a loop equivalent that will hopefully not take too much of CPU power to process.

This is what I have so far:

```
self.wpCpuUsage.display(cpu_percent(interval=1))
```

and this is within **__*init*__** of the QMainWindow class.

I've tried putting it in a for loop, but then it iterates over it, and basically waits for it to iterate and then executes the program.

Help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a `QTimer`[<sup>[reference]</sup>](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtimer.html) object with a callback.

Something like that should work:

```
def call_this():
    self.wpCpuUsage.display(cpu_percent(interval=1))

self.my_timer = QtCore.QTimer()
self.my_timer.timeout.connect(call_this)
self.my_timer.start(1000) #1 second interval
```

Comment: Thanks - I was looking at QTimeDate and its timeChanged signal, but didn't find a way to properly implement it. I guess great minds think alike :)